# TikZ grid lines shifted slightly

Tags: tikz-pgf, line, grids

I know that this is not really important, but it bothers me that I do not know if is an internal rounding error, or there are some offsets I do not know about!? The lines of a `grid` are shifted slightly! It is normally only visible at the far corners at high zoom level. Here I compare a `grid` and a `rectangle`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={circle, magnification=35, size=1cm, connect spies}]
\draw[line cap=rect] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\draw[line width=0.01pt, red] (1cm+0.2pt,-0.1)  -- (1cm+0.2pt,1.1) (1cm-0.2pt,-0.1)  -- (1cm-0.2pt,1.1);
\spy[green] on (1,1) in node at (1.8,1.2);
\draw (0,-2) rectangle (1,-1);
\draw[line width=0.01pt, red] (1cm+0.2pt,-2.1)  -- (1cm+0.2pt,-0.9) (1cm-0.2pt,-2.1)  -- (1cm-0.2pt,-0.9);
\spy[blue] on (1,-1) in node at (1.8,-0.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Spy zoom on corners of grid and rectangle]

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment. Changing to

```
\draw[line cap=rect] (0,0) grid (1.00001, 1.00001);
```

produces the desired result:

[image]

But if this were just a rounding issue, I would expect `\draw[line cap=rect] (0,0) grid (1, 1);` to produce the same image as `\draw[line cap=rect] (0,0) grid (.9, .9);`. But it does not. Using `(.9,.9)` does not draw the second set of lines (which is expected).