# Generating a specific graphic with TikZ

Tags: tikz-styles, grids, shapes, lattice

I am wondering how to generate a specific image with TikZ. This image is essentially a lattice grid without the grid, with a triangle, rectangle, and other shapes overlayed in a particular way. I would also like to be able to notate points on specific lattice points. Here is an example of what I would like to create:

[image: Names of points substitute for lattice points]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to SE. Just showing an image and asking people to do your work for you is frowned upon here. Show your attempt, and people will help make it better or correct it. Thank you.

Comment: @Miyase I didn't know, so I'm sorry. I'm rather new to TikZ, so I have no idea where to even begin when it comes to generating a graphic like this. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Simply have a look at the [TikZ page on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). You'll find a minimal guide, and the main manual starts with a tutorial that should be enough to make the image you want.

Answer (score 5):

The dotted grid can be made with with the `\draw` command with `grid` but use `line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm` (assuming you want 1cm grid spacing). Then the triangle can be made with a `\draw` command and labeled at the vertices using `node`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=2pt, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 1cm](0,0) grid (9,6);
\draw (0,0)node[below]{$(0,0)$}--(8.5,0)node[below]{$(\frac{p}{2},0)$}--(8.5,5.5)node[above]{$(\frac{p}{2},\frac{q}{2})$}--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 It is a nice trick to draw a dot pattern. One weird thing is that you can not always trust it because of rounding error(?) in the grid - try `...(0,0) grid (1,1);` (a dot will be missing). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572993/tikz-grid-lines-shifted-slightly

Comment: @hpekristiansen: Yes. The rounding issue can be resolved with `(0,0) grid (1.1,1.1)`. You can also resolve the linked issue this way, e.g., `(0,0) grid (1.00001,1.00001)`.

Comment: Not important, but just a remark that might be useful in other situations: With `...grid[xstep=-1]...` only horizontal grid lines will be draw and in this situation the dots will only be drawn once.

Answer (score 4):

As @Miyase said, you can found all what you need to draw a TiKz picture on CTAN. This answer is only for a starting point for you.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}
\tikzset{circle node/.style = {circle,inner sep=1pt,draw, fill=white}        
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,9}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,6}
    {
    \fill (\x,\y) circle (1pt);
    }
    \foreach \y in {0,...,6}
    {
    \fill (10,\y) circle (1pt);
    }
    \foreach \x in {0,...,8}
    {
    \fill (\x,7) circle (1pt);
    }
    \draw (0,0)--(9.5,0)--(9.5,6.5)--cycle;
    \node at (0,0)[below]{$(0,0)$};
    \node at (9.5,0)[below]{$(\frac{p}{2},0)$};
    \node at (9.5,6.5)[above]{$(\frac{p}{2},\frac{q}{2})$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]